# Symmetry of Wave- Function and Spin

Tags: wavefunction, quantum-spin, fermions, bosons

Bosons have integral spins and so the total wave-function of a Bosonic system should fundamentally be symmetric under particle exchange. Fermions have half-integral spins and so the total wave-function of a Fermionic system should fundamentally be anti-symmetric under particle exchange. How is this conclusion about the symmetry of the total wave function reached, from the information of the spin of the consituent particles? In other words, what is the proof of the statement? In the book, 'Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics' by Frederick Reif, it is said that this can

> be derived (as was first done by Pauli) from a much
> more profound point of view which examines the requirements for a consistent description
> of the particles in terms of quantum field theory.

Would anyone enlighten me on this fact? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe of use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin–statistics_theorem

Comment: Not the answer but for better understanding: [Why two spin-$1$ bosons could not be in a spin $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1,0\rangle-|0,1\rangle)$ state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/549644/46708)